# 180 nested conditions in a separate file to create a new id variable for each row in the my dataframe

Tags: r, nested, multiple-conditions

I need to identify 180 short sentences written by experiment participants and match to each sentence, a serial number in a new column. I have 180 conditions in a separate file. All the texts are in Hebrew but I attach examples in English that can be understood.

I'm adding example of seven lines from 180-line experiment  data. There are 181 different conditions. Each has its own serial number. So I also add  small 6-conditions example that match this participant data:

```
data_participant <- data.frame("text" =  c("I put a binder on a high shelf", 
                                           "My friend and me are eating chocolate", 
                                           "I wake up with  superhero powers", 
                                           "Low wooden table with cubes", 
                                           "The most handsome man in camopas invites me out", 
                                           "My mother tells me she loves me and protects me", 
                                           "My laptop drops and breaks"), 
                               "trial" = (1:7) )  

data_condition <- data.frame("condition_a" = c("wooden table"  , "eating" , "loves", 
                                               "binder", "handsome", "superhero"), 
                             "condition_b" = c("cubes",  "chocolate", "protects me", 
                                               "shelf","campos", "powers"), 
                             "condition_c" = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "me out", "0"),
                             "i.d." = (1:6) )
```

I decided to use   `ifelse` function and a nested conditions strategy and to write 181 lines of code. For each  condition one line. It's also cumbersome because it requires moving from English to Hebrew. But after 30 lines I started getting an error message:

> contextstack overflow

[A screenshot of the error in line 147 means that after 33 conditions.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQ1f4.png)

In the example, there are at most 3 keywords per condition but in the full data there are conditions with 5 or 6 keywords. (The reason for this is the diversity in the participants' verbal formulations). Therefore, the original table of conditions has 7 columns: on for i.d. no. and the rest are the words identifiers for the same condition with operator "or".

```
data <- mutate(data, script_id = ifelse((grepl( "wooden table" ,data$imagery))|(grepl( "cubes" ,data$imagery))
                                        ,"1",
                                        ifelse((grepl( "eating" ,data$imagery))|(grepl( "chocolate" ,data$imagery))
                                               ,"2",
                                               ifelse((grepl( "loves" ,data$imagery))|(grepl( "protect me" ,data$imagery))
                                                      ,"3", 

                                                      ifelse((grepl( "binder" ,data$imagery))|(grepl( "shelf" ,data$imagery))  
                                                             ,"4", 

                                                             ifelse(  (grepl("handsome"  ,data$imagery)) |(grepl( "campus" ,data$imagery) )|(grepl( "me out" ,data$imagery)) 
                                                                      ,"5",        

                                                                      ifelse((grepl("superhero", data$imagery)) | (grepl( "powers"  , data$imagery   ))
                                                                             ,"6",

                                                                             "181")))))))

# I expect the output will be new  column in the participant data frame 
# with the corresponding ID number for each text.
# I managed to get it when I made 33 conditions rows. And then I started 
# to get an error message contextstack overflow.

final_output <- data.frame("text" =  c("I put a binder on a high shelf", "My friend and me are eating chocolate", 
                                       "I wake up with  superhero powers", "Low wooden table with cubes", 
                                       "The most handsome man in camopas invites me out", 
                                       "My mother tells me she loves me and protects me", 
                                       "My laptop drops and breaks"), 
                           "trial" = (1:7), 
                           "i.d." = c(4, 2, 6, 1, 5, 3, 181) )
```

Comment: What is `data$imagery`?  I think you may need to create a key/val pair dataset and join

Comment: Yes, you could make a table listing each condition and the resulting number, and then use fuzzyjoin::regex_left_join to add the results.

Comment: What would you like to happen with a sentence "I am eating cubes from the shelf?" It has three matches, do we go by the first one encountered, or the one highest up on the lookup table? Or show all matches?

Comment: Different sentences of participants will be identified as having the same i.d. If they match one of the conditions of a specific i.d. Each i.d. has a unique conditions set of its own (for exaple: if the sentence has either word 1 or word 2 or word 3 then i.d. is ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach using `fuzzymatch::regex_left_join`.

```
data_condition_long <- data_condition %>%
  gather(col, text_match, -`i.d.`) %>%
  filter(text_match != 0) %>%
  arrange(`i.d.`)

data_participant %>%
  fuzzyjoin::regex_left_join(data_condition_long %>% select(-col), 
                             by = c("text" = "text_match")) %>%
  mutate(`i.d.` = if_else(is.na(`i.d.`), 181L, `i.d.`)) %>%
  # if `i.d.` is doubles instead of integers, use this:
  # mutate(`i.d.` = if_else(is.na(`i.d.`), 181, `i.d.`)) %>%
  group_by(trial) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-text_match)

# A tibble: 7 x 3
  text                                            trial  i.d.
  <fct>                                           <int> <int>
1 I put a binder on a high shelf                      1     4
2 My friend and me are eating chocolate               2     2
3 I wake up with  superhero powers                    3     6
4 Low wooden table with cubes                         4     1
5 The most handsome man in camopas invites me out     5     5
6 My mother tells me she loves me and protects me     6     3
7 My laptop drops and breaks                          7   181
```

Comment: Hi thank you very much.
I tried this elegant solution with my data in Hebrew - I got: Error: `false` must be an integer vector, not a double vector
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace
> rlang::last_error()
<error>
message: `false` must be an integer vector, not a double vector
class:   `rlang_error`
backtrace:
  1. fuzzyjoin::regex_left_join(...)
 11. dplyr::mutate(., i.d. = if_else(is.na(i.d.), 181L, i.d.))
 12. dplyr:::replace_with(...)
 13. dplyr:::check_type(val, x, name)
 14. dplyr:::glubort(header, "must be {friendly_type_of(template)}, not {friendly_type_of(x)}")

Comment: It sounds like your `i.d.` column is numbers stored as doubles (ie floating point) instead of integers like in your example. That's fine, just replace "181L" with "181" in the code above. `dplyr::if_else` is careful about making both the true and false be the same type. (base R `ifelse` is more permissive.) The `181L` is a way to force R to treat the 181 as an integer; if you use 181 instead, I think it will treat the 181 as a double and it will be consistent with your `i.d.` column.  Alternatively, you could use `ifelse` instead of `if_else` to coerce the two values to be consistent types.